# Is 110 degrees fahrenheit on average bad on a 2019 MacBook Air? (And other problems)

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, google-chrome, memory

I've been using my MacBook air 2019 for quite some time now (9 months) and I've been getting 110 degrees fahrenheit on average with simple use like google chrome or safari. In fact, the highest I have gotten it to reach was 184 degrees fahrenheit. Is this normal? Does anyone else get this issue? Do you think a hard reset could solve this issue? I would like to mention that I have not downloaded any software that takes up much battery. Also, when I'm only using google chrome, my mac tends to only have 100 or fewer megabits of free ram. Another thing that I would like to mention is that my MacBook's REAL battery capacity has been going down by 2% every month. Does anyone know why I'm having all of these problems? Any response would be helpful! Thank you!

Comment: when I'm building something on Xcode, mine reaches 95-100 *C  as per intel power gadget. So it seems fine according to me. Battery capacity going down is a bit troubling.. @zzjjccdd

Comment: 110F is 43C.  The “general” (meaning slight variations depending on individual CPU model) max temp for CPU is 100C or 212F.  Even at 184F, you’re still a long way from reaching the thermal limit.

Comment: Also, there’s three distinct questions here about CPU temp, memory usage, and battery capacity each of which has already been addressed.  If existing questions\answers don’t adequately address your needs, consider offering a [bounty](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) or ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

**Is this normal?** Yes.

**Does anyone else get this issue?** Yes.

**Do you think a hard reset could solve this issue?** No.

As for the battery: some 'settling' over the first few months is expected, but I'd try to take it to Apple before it's 12 months old.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Could you please tell me why a hard reset won't solve the battery issue?

Comment: Because there isn't really a problem with your CPU's temperature. And there isn't really such a thing as a 'hard reset'.  You can try an SMC reset, if you'd like, for the battery. https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201295

Comment: What I mean when I say hard reset is to factory reset the item. Would that help with the battery even though I haven't really downloaded much stuff? Thank you.

Comment: No. Wiping the disk and reinstalling the OS (which amounts to a 'factory reset') will have no effect on the battery's capacity.